# Swift Sort NSDictionary of NSDictionary by Value

Tags: swift, sorting, nsdictionary

I have a NSDictionary of NSDictionaries and I was wondering how do I sort the dictionaries by their value (Name)? The number will change from 0-n. Below is how the structure is setup:

```
let attribute = cumstomClass.Attribute!
```

attribute =

```
-Krqq2AWOqWKys0siTmc
   Description: "" 
   Name: "B"
   Value: ""
-KrqpSvSX7eKqYfvu5ZO
   Description: ""
   Name: "A"
   Value: ""
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Dictionaries are unsorted collections, I’m not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: A dictionary is unordered by definition.

Comment: I am displaying the Name and Value in a collectionView and I am trying to make each name appear in the collectionView in alphabetically order. If that makes more sense?

Meaning the second Dictionary's name will appear first.

Comment: Don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift, use its native Swift counterpart, `Dictionary`. You'll need to add the content of the dictionaries into an array, which you sort based on the name. However, without seeing more code (especially how you declare those dictionaries), it's hard to give an actual answer with working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a `Dictionary` is inherently unsorted, you'll need to use an `Array` instead. Fortunately, this is easily done via functional techniques:

```
guard let dict = nsDict as? [String : [String : String]] else { /* handle the error */ }

let sorted = dict.sorted { ($0.value["Name"] ?? "") < ($1.value["Name"] ?? "") }

print(sorted)
```

This will get you an `Array` of tuples containing the keys and values of the respective dictionaries, sorted by `"Name"`:

```
[(key: "KrqpSvSX7eKqYfvu5ZO", value: ["Name": "A", "Value": "", "Description": ""]),
 (key: "Krqq2AWOqWKys0siTmc", value: ["Name": "B", "Value": "", "Description": ""])]
```

Alternately, you can simply get a sorted array of the `String` keys:

```
let sortedKeys = dict.sorted { ($0.value["Name"] ?? "") < ($1.value["Name"] ?? "") }.map {
    $0.key
}

print(sortedKeys)
```

which outputs:

```
["KrqpSvSX7eKqYfvu5ZO", "Krqq2AWOqWKys0siTmc"]
```

This array of keys can later be used to dynamically look up objects from the dictionary at runtime when populating the collection view. This method will be likely to be more expensive performance-wise than the first approach due to all the dictionary lookups, but will result in lower memory usage if you also need to keep the original dictionary around in its original form for some reason.

Comment: Looks promising! I am implementing now to see if it works!

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but what is the type of `sorted`? Trying to declare it as a class variable and I am not sure how to initialize it.

Comment: It's a function with a trailing closure so you don't need to initialise it.

Comment: I think he meant declare rather than initialize; he probably wants to store it as a property. Anyway, the type would be `[(key: String, value: [String : String])]`.

Comment: Note that, for readability, you could also declare a struct with two properties; one holding the key as a `String`, and the other holding the dictionary as a `[String : String]`. You could add a `map` to the line that creates `sorted` to turn the tuples into instances of this struct, and then the type of the array would be a more readable `[MyStructType]` (replace "MyStructType" with whatever you decide to call the struct).